# Django AttributeError 'NoneType' has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django beginner and I don't know why I'm getting this AttributeError at /id_finder/forms/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' everytime I try to submit the form. Can someone take a look at my code below, maybe I'm not doing something correctly.

forms.py

```py
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 15,required = True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 15,required = True)
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 50,required = True)
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length = 14,required = True)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length = 30,widget = forms.PasswordInput(),required = True)
    region = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Region.objects.all(),empty_label = None,required = True)
    district = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=District.objects.all(),empty_label = None,required = True)
```

models.py

```py
class User(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length = 14)
    Email = models.EmailField(max_length = 50)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    Region = models.OneToOneField('Region', on_delete = models.PROTECT)
    District = models.OneToOneField('District', on_delete = models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.FirstName,self.LastName)

class Region(models.Model):
    RegionName = models.CharField(max_length = 20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.RegionName

class District(models.Model):
    DistrictName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    Region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete = models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.DistrictName
```

views.py

```py
def form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            obj = User() # create a new model object
         #process form data 
            obj.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            obj.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            obj.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            obj.phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
            obj.password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            obj.region = form.cleaned_data['region']
            obj.district = form.cleaned_data['district']
         #save the data
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("Information saved successfully")
    else:
        form = UserForm()
    return render(request,'id_finder/form.html',{'form':form})
```

Traceback:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py" in cmd_query
  395.                                raw_as_string=raw_as_string)

During handling of the above exception (Column 'Region_id' cannot be null), another exception occurred:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py" in _execute_wrapper
  168.             return method(query, args)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py" in execute
  266.                                          raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py" in cmd_query
  398.                                              sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)

During handling of the above exception (1048 (23000): Column 'Region_id' cannot be null), another exception occurred:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  99.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  67.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  76.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in _execute
  84.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py" in execute
  218.         return self._execute_wrapper(self.cursor.execute, query, new_args)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py" in _execute_wrapper
  174.                         utils.IntegrityError(err.msg), sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  683.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py" in _execute_wrapper
  168.             return method(query, args)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py" in execute
  266.                                          raw_as_string=self._raw_as_string)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py" in cmd_query
  398.                                              sqlstate=exc.sqlstate)

During handling of the above exception (Column 'Region_id' cannot be null), another exception occurred:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py" in statement
  606.             return self._executed.strip().decode('utf8')

During handling of the above exception ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'), another exception occurred:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/mohameddiaby/Desktop/Project/Lost_and_Found/id_finder/views.py" in form
  28.             obj.save()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1335.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  103.             sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/operations.py" in last_executed_query
  127.         return force_text(cursor.statement, errors='replace')

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py" in __getattr__
  230.         return getattr(self.cursor, attr)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py" in statement
  608.             return self._executed.strip()
```

Edit: Another thing I noticed is that there are empty values in the query that sends info from form to DB. I don't understand why though

Traceback:

```
buffered    

False

query   

(b'INSERT INTO `id_finder_user` (`FirstName`, `LastName`, `PhoneNumber`, `Email'
 b"`, `Password`, `Date`, `Region_id`, `District_id`) VALUES ('', '', '', '', '"
 b"', '2019-07-07 11:56:25.206852', NULL, NULL)")

raw     

False

raw_as_string   

False

self    

<mysql.connector.connection_cext.CMySQLConnection object at 0x10cb61c18>
```

Comment: You need to include the traceback.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you did not use a `ModelForm`?

Comment: You have error `Column 'Region_id' cannot be null`. Check again in line `obj.region = form.cleaned_data['region']`. Try change to `obj.region_id = form.cleaned_data['region']` with `form.cleaned_data['region']`  is pk of region

Comment: This looks like an integrity error. Since you used a `OneToOneField`, you can only use a destrict once *per* `User`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that's the point, a user can only select one district, and no I don't have a specific reason not to use `ModelForm`

Comment: @mohameddiaby: but a `OneToOneField` means that a destrict only belongs to one user, so no two users can select the *same* district. You probably want to use a `ForeignKey` instead?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ok! I changed to 'ForeignKey` but still getting the same error